# Change data start point in jQuery flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flot

I'm using Flot to graph the clicks per minute for the first 60 minutes on short URLs made: http://cuthut.com/RA5?.

As you can see it starts at minute 0 and goes to minute 59. My question is: how do I get the data to start at 1 and end at 59. In my JSON file the time numbers go from 1-50.

I set the flot options to have ticks from 0 - 60 in increments of 5.

Any help is appreciated.
-Giles

Answer (score 1):

can you set

> xaxis.min = 1

in your options?